# Android: Automating recycler view using Robotium

Tags: robotium

Can we automate RecyclerView using Robotium ?

I need to identify all the items listed in RecyclerView, is it possible using Robotium?

Comment: Hi, are you able to run the test when your activity is extended from ActionBarActivity?